# FaceBook v2.5/me Call, how to set scope

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Calling Facebook Graph API using RestClient.  However, the call returns only name and id or the logged in user.  Can't figure out how to set scope "public_profile, email" so that the call returns email address.

```
 Dim client2 = New RestClient("https://graph.facebook.com")
    webrequest = New RestRequest("v2.5/me", Method.GET)
    webrequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " & access_token)
    webrequest.AddParameter("client_id", "11111111111111111")
    webrequest.AddParameter("access_token", access_token)
    webrequest.AddParameter("client_secret", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
   webrequest.AddParameter("redirect_uri", "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/fbcallback")
    webrequest.AddParameter("scope", "public_profile, email")
webrequest.AddParameter("fields", "id, email,first_name, last_name")
        dim res = client2.Execute(webrequest)
```

This works but return a json that include "`first_name`","`last_name`" and "`id`". Tried putting scope parameter but it didn't make any difference.  No issues with FB profile because Javascript Facebook API works fine. But the requirement is to call the api from server side. Javascript API returns "first_name", "last_name", "id", "email", "verified" and many other fields.

Any inputs?

---SOLVED---

Thanks to the comment from @luschn, tried putting `scope=public_profile,email` in the first call to `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth` endpoint to get `code` (prior to making a call to get `access_token` for `code`) and it worked.

Comment: you are trying to add the scope parameter to a simple api call, instead of using it in the authorization process...for access to /me, you only need an access token as parameter. and a field parameter with a comma separated list of fields you want to get.

Comment: Thanks. that worked.  My comments under ---SOLVED---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scope` is a parameter that only works in the authorization process, you are trying to add it to a simple API call. In the API call itself, you only need the Access Token and a comma separated list of fields: `/me?fields=name,email&access_token=xxx`